# Images show up on JSfiddle but it isn't working on my website

Tags: jquery, image, web, jsfiddle

I used JSFiddle for help but when I transferred it to my website with the below code, the buttons showed but not the images. JSFiddle coding: https://jsfiddle.net/sketchflygirl/4euugfsb/ and my website is using web.com builder. Domain: monroy-art.net.

I used the jquery and script but nothing is helping.

```
<p><button>previous</button>
<button id="next">next</button></p>
<div id="comics"></div>
<p>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/lib/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
$(document).ready(function() {

var imgs = [
'http://onlinebuilder.myregisteredsite.com/matrix/servlet/ShowAsset;jsessionid=3EE39A2568D60590C3FFD69339141C07?id=102911852',
'http://onlinebuilder.myregisteredsite.com/matrix/servlet/ShowAsset;jsessionid=3EE39A2568D60590C3FFD69339141C07?id=102911859',
'http://onlinebuilder.myregisteredsite.com/matrix/servlet/ShowAsset;jsessionid=3EE39A2568D60590C3FFD69339141C07?id=102911864',
'http://onlinebuilder.myregisteredsite.com/matrix/servlet/ShowAsset;jsessionid=3EE39A2568D60590C3FFD69339141C07?id=102911869',
'http://onlinebuilder.myregisteredsite.com/matrix/servlet/ShowAsset;jsessionid=3EE39A2568D60590C3FFD69339141C07?id=102911872',
'http://onlinebuilder.myregisteredsite.com/matrix/servlet/ShowAsset;jsessionid=3EE39A2568D60590C3FFD69339141C07?id=102911877'],

current = 0;

function next() {
current++;
if (current > imgs.length) current = 0;
return imgs[current];
}

function previous() {
current--;
if (current < imgs.length) current = 0;
return imgs[current];
}

var comic = $('<img />').attr('src', imgs[0]);

$('#comics').append(comic);

$('#prev').on('click', function () {
comic.attr('src', prev());
});

$('#next').on('click', function () {
comic.attr('src', next());
});
});
// ]]></script>
</p>
```

Comment: What does the console output?

Comment: monroy-art.net won't load for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried your same code inside `<html><body>` tags and was getting an error on the version of jQuery you are trying to load. I changed it for the one below and it worked. Good luck.

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`